# Lambda Function(Go) can't send email with SES SMTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, smtp, amazon-ses

Hello I've followed the instructions here to try and get my lambda function able to send email via SES SMTP https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-set-up-vpc-endpoints.html

In my Lambda Function I use the net/smtp package and when I try to send the email it gives me this error

> Error sending email alert dial tcp: lookup email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com on *.*.*.1:53: no such host

Here is the code for sending the email that is giving me issues. Note when I rung this Go code locally it works fine.

````
    user := os.Getenv("SMTP_USER")
    password := os.Getenv("SMTP_PASSWORD")

    to := []string{
        "testemail@gmail.com",
    }

    addr := "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587"
    host := "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"

    msg := []byte("From: test@test.com\r\n" +
        "To: test@test.com\r\n" +
        "Subject: Test mail\r\n\r\n" +
        "Email Body \r\n")

    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", user, password, host)

    err = smtp.SendMail(addr, auth, from, to, msg)```
````

Comment: You need to enable DNS resolution for your VPC Endpoint.

Comment: I've found on my VPC the public and private DNS names. Do I use one of those as the host or address instead?

Comment: And make sure you're not in one of these AZs: "Amazon SES does not support VPC endpoints in the following Availability Zones: use1-az2, use1-az3, use1-az5, usw1-az2, usw2-az4, apne2-az4, cac1-az3, and cac1-az4."

Comment: If I connect to my VPC I am able to send emails using the aws smtp server but I am still getting timed out when I try to run it from my lambda function. My lambda function has all possible SES permissions.

Comment: Make sure lambda only runs in the AZ you tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to finally get the SMTP working. Everything in that document in the OP was correct except the security group part. In order to get it to work, I had to set the inbound and outbound rules of my security group (not entirely sure if outbound is necessary) to use the entire IP address range of the subnet in my VPC for use1-az1 for source/destination respectively.